# GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Doamin) is returning null for non persisted domain in Grails-3.2.4

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails3.2.0

I have Two domains.

```
class ABC{

    String xyz

    static mapping = {
        discriminator column: 'ABC_TYPE_ID'
    }
}
```

and

```
class XYZ extends ABC{

    static mapWith = "none"

    static mapping = {
        discriminator value: 3
    }   
}
```

In Grails 2.5.5 below line works perfectly fine but after making the required changes it is not working in Grails-3.2.4 and is giving null.

```
Mapping mapping = new GrailsDomainBinder().getMapping(XYZ) //Works fine Grails 2.5.5

Mapping mapping = GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(XYZ) // Giving null in Grails-3.2.4
```

Please help me in getting the Mapping object from the XYZ domain.

My findings:

I am using oracle db with commented **#dbCreate:''** in application.yml.

After commenting **static mapWith = "none"** in XYZ domain i am getting the Mapping object and the corresponding table is not created in DB because of **#dbCreate:''**.

Are there any issue with this approach? if yes please provide me with alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The static state part has been removed in recent versions of GORM. You need to use the `MappingContext` object to get what you want:

```
MappingContext mappingContext = .. // can be injected via Spring
Mapping mapping = (Mapping)mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(Foo).mapping.mappedForm
```

See http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/model/MappingContext.html